# How to send integration test results, if analysis results have already been transmitted?

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

I have an integration testing stage in our pipeline. This stage does not immediately run after the build and the unit-tests.

How can I send the integration test results to SonarQube, if the Sonar Analyzer results have already been transmitted?

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use the standard procedure?

Comment: what standard procedure? im not running integration tests the same time were doing build and unit tests.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770) page to include code coverage results during a SonarQube analysis. Is executing the SonarQube analysis after executing the unit- and integrationtests an option?